# How to check HDCP Level on Android (TV) for API < 28?

Tags: android, android-tv, hdcp

I have a Android TV stick and I would like to distinguish what HDCP version is supported?

I already have found something and it seems to work:

```
    try {
        val uuid = UUID.fromString("1f83e1e8-6ee9-4f0d-ba2f-5ec4e3ed1a66")
        val mediaDrm = MediaDrm(uuid)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            mediaDrm.connectedHdcpLevel
        }
    } catch (use : UnsupportedSchemeException) {
        Log(use.localizedMessage)
    }
```

But [the documentation says](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaDrm#getConnectedHdcpLevel())

> Added in API level 28

How can read the HDCP level for older API < 28?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57896720/detect-widevine-drm-hdcp-protection-level
Does this answer help?

Answer (score 0):

As per your questions **only On API V28 or before** see here...

You can get away with this, but may have to check your version level before getting into this.

---

```
// CHECK if V28 or before... ONLY then enter the REST of the below code...
val algorithms = mediaDrm.getPropertyString("maxHdcpLevel")

// you also Then manually suppress the warning error/constant


// get your maxHdcpLevel manually
val stringProperties = arrayOf(
                MediaDrm.PROPERTY_VENDOR,
                MediaDrm.PROPERTY_VERSION,
                MediaDrm.PROPERTY_DESCRIPTION,
                MediaDrm.PROPERTY_ALGORITHMS,
                "maxHdcpLevel")

val devicePropertiesMap = ... MapOf<String, String>()

for (attributes in stringProperties) {
     devicePropertiesMap [attributes ] = mediaDrm.getPropertyString(attributes )
     Log.mydebug(attributes , mediaDrm.getPropertyString(attributes ))
     }

Log.mydebug("maxHdcpLevel:", "${devicePropertiesMap ["maxHdcpLevel"]}")
```

---

Now you can access this stuff easily.. with the code sample below

```
 val myDeviceHdcpLevel    = mediaDrm.getPropertyString("hdcpLevel")
 val myDeviceMaxHdcpLevel = mediaDrm.getPropertyString("maxHdcpLevel")
```